# Unconnected wires doubts

Tags: scala, chisel

I try implement the module for my project. The module rough structure as below:

```
class TOP extend Module{
  val io = IO(new Bundle {some IO intend to connect to other module })

  val queue = Module (new Queue(UInt(32.W), 5) )//I instantiate queue for special purpose for my design, and I do not connect the queue to other

  when(condition1){
    queue.io.enq.valid := true.B
    queue.io.enq.bits  := 5.U
  }
  ........
  when(conditionN){
    queue.io.deq.ready := true.B
    val retrieve data out:= queue.io.deq.bits 
  }  
}
```

When I run it, I encounter problems associated with unconnected wires.

After reading the page (https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Unconnected-Wires).
There are some questions that I cannot figure out with the page.

(1) Every module IO must to connect other IO of other module?

(2) DontCare: be connected to an output signal, indicating that that signal is intentionally not driven.
Does it mean not driven at initial stage, however, it can be driven when some condition happen?

Or it is not driven for whole time?
ig:

```
io.out.debugOption := DontCare
when (condition){ io.out.debugOption := true}
```

(3) What is the value with applying DontCare?

```
queue.io.enq.valid := DontCare
```

I am beginner for Chisel. Sorry if the question I ask is simple.

Comment: Sorry, was this supposed to be 'doubts'? If yes, you probably should choose a more descriptive title anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: Chisel reports unconnected IO's that are not at the top level as errors in order to make it harder to make mistakes. `DontCare` is a way to suppress those errors if you think you really don't want a signal connected to something.

Specifically
(1) Every IO of a sub-module should be connected to something, but it does not have to be to another IO, it could be to a literal value or some other component of the parent Module.

(2) `DontCare` allows a developer to leave a wire unconnected and suppress the errors. Often this is for backward compatibilty or perhaps some sub-module that has functionality you need, but also some you don't. Modern better practices would be to use optional IO signals in sub-modules with these properties.

Your debug example should work but it would probably be better to just do 
`io.out.debug := false.B` instead. DontCare will leave the signal in an indeterminate state which could easily be true, which could easily have bad consequences.

(3) As stated previously DontCare let's the developer acknowledge that a signal may not be set.

That being said, there is a situation when using `Decoupled` which is used by the `Queue` Module where a signal may have some edge case in which it is unconnected, but that case does occur in actual operation of the circuit. It is generally best to give it an initial assignment to a literal value, subsequent use of the signal will override that initial assignment for other conditions.  This is called "last connect semantics", i.e. last assignment wins.

If this is too vague perhaps you can provide a little more code examples and a small unit test that illustrates the problem.